# Creating multiple draggable with jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Using jquery, How can I create multiple draggables using loops through javascript? I want to create something like this. Using AUTOCOMPLETE, I want the user to select a tag and use that as a display name for the draggable which can be dropped to the droppable screen. Since, I want to give user an option to select multiple tags one after another, I want to add this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for jQuery-UI all day long. Check out documentation at http://jqueryui.com/demos/

They've got the autocomplete and the draggables, and droppables.

Give all your draggables a class then call

```
$('.dragme').draggable();
```

**UPDATE**

Implement jQueryUI in the `<head>` section of your webpage (first download from site)

```
<script src="javascripts/jqueryui.min.js"></script>
```

Give your "draggable" elements a universal class to categorize by

```
<ul>
  <li class="dragMe">Drag</li>
  <li class="dragMe">Drag me too!</li>
  <li class="dragMe">Drag me as well!</li>
  <li>Don't drag me!</li>
</ul>
```

In your script, initialize the draggable elements

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.dragMe').draggable();
</script>
```

Use similar process for the droppable elements

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.dropMe').droppable();
</script>
```

You can add a function for when the element is dropped like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.dropMe').droppable({
    drop: function() {
      //Your code here
      // ui.draggable refers to the dropped element
    }
  });
</script>
```

I think that's more than a fair start. Like I said, look through the documentation and look through the code examples there. They'll also have a bunch on the autocomplete. I also recommend the book "JQUERY: NOVICE TO NINJA". It really helped me get off the ground.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? Since I am a newbie for javascript and jquery, I am finding it difficult to grasp. Perhaps, little pseudo-code would make it much more clear for me.